# jasmine test requires $window to be defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I'm running jasmine tests with gulp task and I want to test a directive. Directive itself is a simple toggle button component and requires no dependencies. So, I'm following [this](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/06/introduction-to-unit-test-directives/) tutorial, starting with

```
beforeEach(module('app'));

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {
   scope = $rootScope.$new();
}));

it('does something', function() {
   expect(scope).toBeDefined();
});
```

But the test fails with this obscure log

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$window.PUBLISH_SETTINGS.webApiUrl')
```

Somehow, angular calls seemingly unconnected piece of code from inside my application, which requires $window to be defined. What is happening here? How do I isolate my directive so I won't need to mess with $window?